# Store and Call Ruby Method without using .method/.call

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

I'm adding unit tests to a large batch of code and am looking for a way to insert fake methods in for testing purposes. The problem is that, as far as I know in Ruby, to pass a method in one must use `ClassName.method(:method_name)`, and then refactor the method I'm testing to use `boo.call()` instead of just `boo()`. Is there an easier way to do this than refactoring everything to use `.method` and `.call`?

Comment: maybe method mocks will help you? I'm not sure for test:unit, but in rspec they're great.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I already knew that flexmock could do this but wanted something a bit more expressive, and it's hard to find something more expressive than pure Ruby (that is, fakes), but not at the cost of refactoring a huge chunk of my code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just pass lambdas? I mean, lambda is just an anonymous method/function as you know it from other languages, so it should work fine. Eg:

```
fake_method = lambda { |n| "do something with n" }

def other_method(fm)
  #...
  fm.call
  #...
end

other_method(fake_method)
```

You still need to call `.call` though

Comment: So that solves me having to use `:method`, which is half the problem, but then still relies on my having to refactor a lot of stuff to use `.call`. Is there a way I can do just `fm()`?

Comment: unfortunately, no, there isn't

Comment: Either of these aren't a terrible idea if I were starting a new project from scratch, but it isn't worth it on an existing, non-trivially large set of code.